# Is there any way to get nzshowsearch to be case insensitive?

Tags: angular

My data is loaded from the backend using a json file and stored in a form. I'd like to know if there's any way to make the search box find results irrespective of the case being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easy way to do this is with the method toUpperCase() or toLowerCase()

example :

```
if(string1.toLowerCase() === string2.toLowerCase()){
   //do something
}
```